# Osgi Bundle update and ResourceBundle

Tags: java, osgi, resourcebundle

Lest's suppose we have two osgi bundles: bundleA and bundleB. In bundleB we have some `texts.properties`. So, in bundleA we do

```
ResourceBundle rb= 
        ResourceBundle.getBundle("com/foo/texts",locale, classFromBundleB.getClassLoader());
```

Now, we update bunldeB or totally remove it and install and start new version of bundleB that contains new version of `texts.properties`. And two questions :

1. What happens to existing 'rb'? Must it work?
2. If after new version of bundleB came we do the same code as above - will we see in `rb` new version of `texts.properties`? Or we need to do additional actions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since bundleA has a reference to classFromBundleB, unless bundleA is refreshed, it will continue to maintain the classFromBundleB from the original bundleB. And since ResourceBundle maintains a cache, you will keep getting the same rb. So after updating bundleB, you will need to refresh the bundles which depend upon the classes from bundleB.